# What data are we capturing in Google Analytics from an embedded iFrame we own that resides on a third-party site?

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, cross-domain

I was asked to create a Google id for our marketing department to be able to use to track their ads. I had no idea these ads were being delivered as an iFrame (without head tags, just html) into a third-party site (that can be on the web or on desktop software). Now the department wants to know what they've been tracking, and I can't seem to figure it out. I see a TON of pages, but I can't actually find the url of the iFrame. Are these pages the containers for that iFrame? Am I going to be able to pull anything useful/accurate from this data?

FYI - the google analytics code is on the iFrame and it looks mostly like this (I pulled out a ton of CSS and HTML that isn't necessary to see):

```
 <!-- Google Analytics -->
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-2']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

```
<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";/*! normalize.css v3.0.3 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}
body{margin:0; padding:0}
</style>

<div id="modal_inject">

    <!--Modal content goes here-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

cross-domain Iframe tracking can be really tricky to set up.

First, It is necessary to **have access to both domains** (parent domain and iframe domain), which you have.

Then , **what do you want to track** ?... with GTM you can pull up a lot of data... but you need to know exactly what is very interesting for you business (pages view, form sent, videos viewed...).

Some insights...

**Wanting to know what is going on on the iframe** > GA code on iframe domain sending data to a Google Analytics Property (same or different property of the parent domain).

**Wanting to track users on the parent domain AND the iframe ?** > Need cross-domain tracking (GA code inside both domains, sending data to the same GA property,and allowing GA Linker for cross-domain tracking).

**Wanting to make parent domain and Iframe communicates ?** (sending each other some data) > the hardest task because you will face the "[same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Security/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)" with an Iframe domain being different from the parent doamin.

here are some useful resources that might help you :

- [Tracking Cross-domain Iframes from Simo Ahava](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/tracking-cross-domain-iframes-upgraded-solution/)
- [Cross-domain iframe tracking with GTM](https://www.knewledge.com/en/blog/2013/11/cross-domain-tracking-for-iframes-with-gtm/)
- [Google analytics and Iframes by Bounteous](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2015/10/21/google-analytics-iframes-form-submissions/)

Hope This can help.

Comment: Hi, @B4b4j1  Thanks for answering. My apologies, I left out the most important part: Unfortunately, we do not have access to the Parent at all. Their iFrame is being injected into third-party software.  I have done just a ton of searching around, reading up on Cross-domain tracking, etc. But this is not the situation we have. So sorry I left that out. I realize that was the most important detail. :-(   I was really hoping to track the iFrame almost like it's own HTML page, but it doesn't seem to be doing that. In fact, I'm not seeing any data on specifically just the iFrame.

Comment: No worries.. I tried to understand your issue and bring some insights. I do not know how is build your website and how everything is embedded... But if you can put a GA code inside one domain (iframe or not), you can track it.